# How to find unreferenced objects in scala

Tags: scala, object, lazy-initialization

I'm trying to create a map of all objects extending a specific class. I want to have access to this list before the objects are used in any other way. I tried this code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

abstract class Registered(tag:String) {
    Registered.registry(getClass.getName) = tag
    val x = 1
}

object Registered {
    val registry = mutable.Map[String, String]()
}

object objA extends Registered("foo")

object objB extends Registered("bar")

object TheMain {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        listem
        touchem
        listem
    }
    def listem = {
        println(s"listing ${Registered.registry.size} entries:")
        for ((k,v) <- Registered.registry) yield println(s"$k: $v")
    }
    def touchem = {
        val x = objA.x + objB.x
    } 
}
```

which outputs:

```
listing 0 entries:
listing 2 entries:
objB$: bar
objA$: foo
```

I need the first line to also list 2 entries. I know this doesn't work because the map is always empty: object initialization is lazy and so I cannot refer to an object until it has been referenced some other way.

What is a good way to create such a registry? Can (Should) I do this using reflection somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but you could have a look at https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections, a library that can tell you the children of a given class.

Comment: If your objects are always static, then you can use macro to populate your map at compile time.

Comment: Btw, what you want to achieve is very unconventional. Classes should not do anything without an explicit call. You could move the registration process to a register() method and call the method explicitly after declaration.

Comment: This is not possible. How do you imagine this would work? What if an object is defined in another file? Another package? You don't want your program to scan the entire classpath, and instantiate everything everywhere, that's just insane. What is this use case for this anyway?

Comment: Use `knownSubClasses` in macro and make the base class sealed.

Comment: my usecase is not dissimilar to sbt's 'run', when multiple mains are present. It lists them all and asks you which one you want to run. In my case I want to look at all objects of a given type and use one with a specific tag. This tag comes from a command line argument.

Comment: @DavidFrank - Classes should perhaps not do anything without an explicit call, but _instances_ should. For every normal non-lazy val or var the constructor is called upon instantiation. If I were to do:
    `val o = new Registered("foo")`
why would that be so different from
    `object o extends Registered("foo")`
where the first calls the constructor immediately, while the second won't?

Comment: @gens if `object` behaved the same as `val` why would you need both? ;)

Comment: @Dima because I cannot make a top level val.

Comment: Here, you explained why they behave differently :) You can't execute "top level code" either, can you?

Comment: @Dima Perhaps not in Scala, but what is the technical reason not to? Other languages allow you to define top-level objects and variables just fine, and they are initialized when the program starts. I understand the efficiency argument, but a way to force objects to be non lazy initialized could be useful.

Comment: You can define top level objects. You cannot run "top level code". Other languages do not let you do that either. Every piece of code is executed in a context of thread, starting at a thread root.

Comment: @Dima How is that true? Here are [cpp](https://gist.github.com/balihoo-gens/6b7248dc5be9e3822f56) and [python](https://gist.github.com/balihoo-gens/b9559b7ae36fcefccf77) examples. Either way, this discussion is not helping me. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an answer to what you add in the comment than to the original question: "*In my case I want to look at all objects of a given type and use one with a specific tag. This tag comes from a command line argument.*"

Why not just create the object dynamically in that case? Like this, maybe:

```
class Registered(tag:String)

object Registered {
    val registry = mutable.Map[String,String]
    def apply(tag: String) = registered.getOrElseUpdate(tag, new Registered(tag))         
}
```

Or, you insist on statically created instances, you can do this (and not even need the registry):

```
sealed class Registered(tag:String) 
object objA extends Registered("foo")
object objB extends Registered("bar")
object Registered {
    def apply(tag: String) = tag match {
        case "foo" => objA
        case "bar" => objB
        case _ => throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unknown tag: %s".format(x))
    }
}
```

Comment: Dynamically creating the objects is not an option; they are existing singletons containing main functions themselves.

The second option seems to do the same as my initial example, unless I am misunderstanding. When is the apply called? If I add a main to this, I still won't be able to get to objA or B until it is explicitly referenced.

Comment: Well, you said, you are passing a tag on command line ... So, your `main` could then look like `def main(args: Array[String]) = Registered(args(0)).doStuff()`

Comment: haha, I see. So with this, I still need to manually refer explicitly to every object in apply's case statement. Why even bother extending Registered at all? The whole point of this is to not keep a double administration. I think I'll go back at looking at reflection, or (ugh) DelayedInit

Comment: Well "why bother extending Registered" is a good question :) Frankly, I don't even know why bother with tags on command line to begin with. If you want to run `objA`, why not just run it?

Comment: We're getting away from my actual problem. I appreciate your search for a work around, but it isn't really helpful. If I could 'just run it', obviously I would. My example is contrived but explains my issue well. To humor you: The real world problem is more complicated; I have potentially hundreds of mains of which I know nothing but a set of tags. A user supplies a set of tags and I need to act on one or more objects matching these tags. Sure, one way is to scan all the source and make a huge list of all objects, but I am trying to automate that, so I do not keep a double admin by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).  You should be able to do something like this to find all classes in `some.package.name` that inherit from class `Thingy`:

```
def getThingies(): Set[Class[_ <: Thingy]] = {
  val reflections = new Reflections("some.package.name");
  reflections.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Thingy]);
}
```

Of course, you could specify `classOf[Object]` to get all classes in the package.  You can also search for packages that have certain annotations.

Comment: Cool. I will definitely try this out. I am however still hoping for a pure scala solution, so I'm also looking into using a [runtime mirror](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors$RuntimeMirror).